# Where should I put username/password for http basic authentication in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, basic-authentication

I am going to use http-basic-authentication in a rails app.  I watched this railscast to figure out how do do that:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication

In the video he says not to put the username and password directly in the code.  Where should I put them then?

I am using rails 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to move them into config files. Ceck out [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file) about "Application Configuration".