# Where can I store the password/username combo that's used in Rails' http_basic_authentication_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, basic-authentication

I'm trying to use Rails' http_basic_authenticate_with method to secure a personal app. The docs show this as an example:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "dhh", :password => "secret", :except => :index

   def index
     render :text => "Everyone can see me!"
   end

   def edit
     render :text => "I'm only accessible if you know the password"
   end
end
```

I'm looking for a way to keep the password and username out of my controller's code. I've heard about environment variables or "config files" as an option, but I don't know how to implement this.

I've seen this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574519/where-should-i-put-username-password-for-http-basic-authentication-in-rails-app) about where to put the username/password for http basic auth, but the answer (a Railscast) was for Rails 2.x.

Thanks!

Edit: I should clarify that I'm using a repository and therefore need some sort of file I can check out of git...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was me, I'd use SettingsLogic and store them in there.

https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic

If you wanted them to come from the environment then you'd do something like this in your controller:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => MY_USER, :password => MY_PASS, :except => :index
```

And then in say config/initializers/my_user_pass.rb:

```
MY_USER=ENV['SOME_USER']
MY_PASS=ENV['SOME_PASS']
```

Then be sure that how ever you Rails app gets loaded that SOME_USER and SOME_PASS are set as environment variables.

Also, all of the variable names I've picked above are pretty horrible.  Please pick something better.

Also also.. unless you need them in your environment, I'd really suggest SettingsLogic.  It's nice for this and so many other things.

Comment: Settings logic is good but I find it to be overkill.  Why use a gem when a few lines of code and a YAML file accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @JoshL, why use a gem _or_ a YAML file when the existing config files already do the same thing? :)

Comment: @JoshL Because APP_CONFIG[:name] is uglier IMHO than Settings.name. Also nesting is nicer.

Comment: @PinnyM I would argue that credentials are different than settings.  Some stuff is perfectly fine to store in source control, but certain data (e.g. production keys for credit card gateways, database passwords) really should not be widely distributed.  Obviously this question may not warrant the kind of security paranoia I am expressing ... but this is a *really* important thing for those of us writing real apps to keep in mind.  Passwords are private, secret and should be controlled.  Putting them in source code isn't a good idea.  Putting them in a carefully controlled file is better.

Comment: @PinnyM Because I don't want to blend Rails settings with my app settings, but I could easily be persuaded :)

Comment: @tharrison, who said anything about source control?  I imagine a real production.rb file isn't source controlled and managed by a deploy system such as Capistrano that copies over from a predetermined location on the secure server.

Comment: @PinnyM I assumed source control (and an edit of OP confirms).  I am sure we agree that the important point is just that in a real production environment, "somehow" the secure data in an app should be controlled.  Don't want to get in a flame war, just wanted to make the point.  Peace?

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do, IMO, is to use a yaml file and application level variables.

Inside of your application.rb above the rails init try something like this:

```
raw_config = File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(raw_config)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
```

and then create an app_config.yml file with keys like such:

```
name: dhh
password: secret
```

you can also setup environment specific ones as well with:

```
development:
  name: dhh
  password: secret
production:
  name: whatever
  password: sauce
```

Once you do that you can reference the application level variables like this:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => APP_CONFIG[:name], :password => APP_CONFIG[:password], :except => :index
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Great answer!  A couple items to add: 1) "basic auth" and "secure" don't belong in the same sentence; basic auth is a very thin layer, and 2) I like to put stuff that not everyone (in the company) should have access to in a file that is *not* checked in.  Anyone who needs to deploy will need access, but presumably that's only a few people.

Comment: Sorry, where inside of application.rb do the first two assignments go? Is rails init the module with the name of my application?

Comment: @hlh, yes, above that should be fine

Comment: Hmm. I wrote the code as JoshL described, but am getting an 'unitialized constant' exception for APP_CONFIG

Comment: For Rails 3, try something like this:  ```raw_config = File.read(Rails.root + "/config/app_config.yml")```